# Python list comprehension: return value matching multiple if statements, else return other value

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement

I'm working on list comprehension in python, and am having difficulty condensing my code into a single list comprehension statement.

I'm writing a function to search a list of movie dictionaries that looks like this:

```
    movies = [
    {
    "name": "Usual Suspects", 
    "imdb": 7.0,
    "category": "Thriller"
    },
    {
    "name": "Hitman",
    "imdb": 6.3,
    "category": "Action"
    },
    {
    "name": "Dark Knight",
    "imdb": 9.0,
    "category": "Adventure"
    }
    ]
```

I'm trying to write a function that takes in an input of a movie name, checks the imdb score, and returns True if the score > 5.5, but returns false if the score doesn't meet this criteria.

Writing in traditional code, I accomplished this like the following:

```
    def good_movie(movie_name):
        for m in movies:        #for each item in movies...
            if m["name"] == movie_name:       #see if movie_name == "name", if it does...
                if m["imdb"] > 5.5:      # See if the movie's score is greater than 5.5...
                    return "True"      # If it is, return "true"
                else:        #otherwise
                    return "False"       #return false
```

I've been able to write this in list comprehension to return true, but can't get the function to work if I also want to return false when the movie doesn't meet the proper score criteria.

The short version that works is:

```
    def good_movie(movie_name):
        return ["True" for m in movies if m["name"] == movie_name if m["imdb"] > 5.5]
```

However, I'd like to be able to return a value of False if the movie_name doesn't meet both of the if statements listed here.  I've tried it a few different ways, but can't figure out how to make it work.

Something like this DOESN'T work:

```
    def good_movie(movie_name):
        return ["True" if m["imdb"] > 5.5 and if m["name"] == movie_name else "False" for m in movies]
```

I thought maybe adding the "and" between the if statements would help (otherwise, it would think of the if statements as independent, rather than connected).

I've worked with this back and forth a number of times, but any assistance anyone could provide would help me better understand how these sorts of list comprehensions work in the future.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your replies.  This was my first post on stack overflow, and I'm already blown away by the amount of response I've gotten for my small request. I understand that list comprehension is not the best way to address this problem in a real-world application, I am just in the process of learning list comprehension, and wanted to see how I could solve this problem in normal python, without importing pandas, etc.  Thank you again to everyone who contributed!

Comment: Why are you using `"True"` and `"False"` strings instead of Python's `True` and `False` booleans?

Comment: This is not a case for a list comprehension. List comprehensions are not just a snazzy way to write loops; they are for *building lists*, and you don't want to build a list anywhere here.

Comment: @user2357112 That is true, but generator expressions are similar and they are used for looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This just uses a couple of shortcuts. I think `next` is probably the nicest way to get the first element of an iterable satisfying a condition.

```
target_movie = "Hitman"

def good(movies, target_movie):
    return next(movie["imdb"] > 5.5 for movie in movies if movie["name"] == target_movie)

good(movies, target_movie)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm admittedly brand new to python and programming in general, so I'm still familiarizing myself with the various methods python has available.

My understanding of the solution as you wrote it is that the next method is iterating over each item in the movies list, and is returning "true" or "false" for whether the movie's score is over 5.5 once it's determined that movie["name"] == target_movie.  If it can't find a movie name matching target_movie, it also returns false.  Is that more or less correct?

Comment: Never mind that last bit, it seems the function results in error if the target_movie can't be found in the movies list. This is a separate issue to be resolved, but you've helped me in breaking through the problem I was trying to solve.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. To understand my solution a little more I suggest running `list` instead of `next` on the generator expression, i.e. `list(movie["imdb"] > 5.5 for movie in movies if movie["name"] == target_movie)`. `next` just gets the first element of this instead of all elements. Your description looks basically right, except if `movie["name"] == target_movie` is not satisfied, nothing will be added to the list at all (not `False`). Read about Python comprehensions to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == movie_name)
```

Combine with a lookup of the score based on index and you're good!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing multiple evaluations of scores, then you should rethink your data structure. If you only ever once iterate through that list of dictionaries then it may be ok doing so, but you eventually want to evaluate more than one movie. If you call evaluate for the same list of movies more than one time, this is way more efficient than looping through the list everytime:

```
scores = {d['name']: d['imdb'] for d in movies}

def evaluate(name):
    return scores[name] > 5.5
```

It uses a dictcomp to build a mapping of names to scores first, and then the function is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to loop through lists, but maybe you can think about other ways.  Pandas will be much easier to work with in your case.

```
    import pandas as pd

    movies = [
     {
     "name": "Usual Suspects", 
     "imdb": 7.0,
     "category": "Thriller"
     },
     {
     "name": "Hitman",
     "imdb": 6.3,
     "category": "Action"
     },
     {
     "name": "Dark Knight",
     "imdb": 9.0,
     "category": "Adventure"
     }
     ]

     movie_pd = pd.DataFrame(movies)
     # find movies that have more than 7.5 scores in imbd.
     movie_pd['good_movie'] = movie_pd[ movie_pd['imdb'] > 7.5].name
```

Output:

```
  In[6]:movie_pd
  Out[6]: 
        category  imdb            name   good_movie
    0   Thriller   7.0  Usual Suspects          NaN
    1     Action   6.3          Hitman          NaN
    2  Adventure   9.0     Dark Knight  Dark Knight
```